# Make a test in xUnit with Assert.Contains

Tags: c#, xunit

I try to make a test with xUnit finding the Id in a query in the controller.

My code its.

```
 public class CuestionarioTest
{
public readonly CuestionarioController _controller;
private readonly Mock<ICuestionarioServicio> _cuestionariosServicio;
private readonly Mock<IRespuestaServicio> _respuestaServicio;

public CuestionarioTest()
{
    _cuestionariosServicio = new Mock<ICuestionarioServicio>();
    _respuestaServicio = new Mock<IRespuestaServicio>();
    _controller = new  CuestionarioController(_cuestionariosServicio.Object, _respuestaServicio.Object);
}    
[Fact]
public async Task ComprobarBusquedaPorId()
{
    int id = 1;
    var result = await _controller.BuscarPorId(id);
    //Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    Assert.Contains(1, result.);    
}
```

}

This is my method

```
public class CuestionarioController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICuestionarioServicio _cuestionariosServicio;
    private readonly IRespuestaServicio _respuestaServicio;

    public CuestionarioController(ICuestionarioServicio cuestionarioServicio, IRespuestaServicio respuestaServicio)
    {
        _cuestionariosServicio = cuestionarioServicio;
        _respuestaServicio = respuestaServicio;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> BuscarPorId(int id)
    {
        return Ok(await _cuestionariosServicio.ObtenerPorId(id));
    }
```

I don't know how can validate if the result contain the Id with the result.

Please help.

Comment: Can you add the signature of the method you're testing? And the definition of whatever type you're returning from that method

Comment: i add my controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801094/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-taskiactionresult-returned-through-an-api-for-uni/50807112#50807112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801094/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-taskiactionresult-returned-through-an-api-for-uni/50807112#50807112)

Answer (score 2):

If you cast the result, you can pull out the value:

```
var value = (result as OkObjectResult).Value;
Assert.Contains(1, value);
```

Comment: i have a error, the Object can change to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as` operator to perform conversion with compatible types.

```
        var actionResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
        Assert.Contains("1", actionResult.Value as string);
```

The `as` operator returns null if the conversion is not possible.